# Integration on $ \mathbb{P}^n ( \mathbb{R} ) $.

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, lebesgue-integral

Could you tell me please, when and how we calculate the integral of a function on $ \mathbb{P}^n ( \mathbb{R} ) $ ? Do you have some references about that ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $\mathbb P^n(\mathbb R)$ is isometric to the upper semishpere (by forgetting the equator, which is of measure zero). Thus it is the same as integration on the upper hemisphere.

Comment: You need a metric (or a volume form at least) in order to integrate. The most natural choice of a metric is the projection of the metric from the sphere (which is a 2:1 cover): it is invariant with respect to projective transformation.